# How to decrease the height of rdlc report header?

Tags: rdlc

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under "Textbox Properties" --> "General Tab" you will find two sizing options:

Uncheck `Allow height to increase`,
then check `Allow height to decrease`

Comment: What if the header is in text field not in table? how can you decrease the height of Header? Thanks!